# Rails dont send email in docker

Tags: gmail

i need a help.

I try send email using rails and default mail service. In developering all ok, but after dockerize project i get error: "wrong authentication type 'plain'".

------------------------ My docker file ------------------------

```
FROM ruby:3.1.2

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app


COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .
RUN gem update bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . .

ENV RAILS_ENV production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

------------------------ My .env file ------------------------

```
SMTP_ADDRESS='smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT=587
SMTP_AUTHENTICATION='plain'
SMTP_USER_NAME='login'
SMTP_PASSWORD='password'

DATABASE_NAME='dbname'
DATABASE_USERNAME='dbuser'
DATABASE_PASSWORD='dbpassword'
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_HOST='host.docker.internal'
```

------------------------ My production.rb file ------------------------

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
host = 'example.com' #replace with your own url
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }


config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'],
:port                 => ENV['SMTP_PORT'],
:authentication       => ENV['SMTP_AUTHENTICATION'],
:user_name            => ENV['SMTP_USER_NAME'],
:password             => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none' #Use this because ssl is activated but we have no certificate installed. So clients need to confirm to use the untrusted url.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need to pass the `ENV` variables into the Dockerfile? Or if you have a docker-compose file, pass it there